# No source line info when using g++ 4.8.5 with AddressSanitizer

Tags: c++, gcc, address-sanitizer

Given the following HeapOutOfBounds example from https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerExampleHeapOutOfBounds

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int* array = new int[100];
  array[0] = 0;
  int res = array[argc + 100];  // BOOM
  delete [] array;
  return res;
}
```

If I compile this with gcc 13.2 and the flags `-O -g -fsanitize=address` then I get source code line info in the AddressSanitizer output (see also https://godbolt.org/z/bKT14hPY7):

```
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x6140000001d4 at pc 0x0000004011ea bp 0x7ffd25bcadf0 sp 0x7ffd25bcade8
READ of size 4 at 0x6140000001d4 thread T0
    #0 0x4011e9 in main /app/example.cpp:7
    #1 0x7fcf4fc29d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: a43bfc8428df6623cd498c9c0caeb91aec9be4f9)
    #2 0x7fcf4fc29e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: a43bfc8428df6623cd498c9c0caeb91aec9be4f9)
    #3 0x4010b4 in _start (/app/output.s+0x4010b4) (BuildId: 58e1fe7163c2e2678cfb97f52b278ca53b60eecf)

0x6140000001d4 is located 4 bytes after 400-byte region [0x614000000040,0x6140000001d0)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fcf503a9678 in operator new[](unsigned long) (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xdb678) (BuildId: 5ce9c09d3612315d01d50bcaafaea176e7ddab77)
    #1 0x401182 in main /app/example.cpp:5
```

If I do the same with a much older version (to which I'm currently stuck due to some technical debt), namely gcc 4.8.5 and the same compiler flags, then I *don't* get source code line info in the AddressSanitizer Output (see https://godbolt.org/z/T3zr8Exfb):

```
=================================================================
==1== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602e0001fdf4 at pc 0x4011e6 bp 0x7ffe7f16b610 sp 0x7ffe7f16b608
READ of size 4 at 0x602e0001fdf4 thread T0
    #0 0x4011e5 (/app/output.s+0x11e5)
    #1 0x7fa7d4229d8f (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f)
    #2 0x7fa7d4229e3f (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f)
    #3 0x4010a4 (/app/output.s+0x10a4)
0x602e0001fdf4 is located 4 bytes to the right of 400-byte region [0x602e0001fc60,0x602e0001fdf0)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fa7d4e116da (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-4.8.5/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0+0x116da)
    #1 0x401189 (/app/output.s+0x1189)
```

Is it possible to have source code location info in the AddressSanitizer output for gcc 4.8.5?  If 'yes', how?  Or was this not supported yet in that version?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `addr2line` to convert the offsets to line numbers?

Comment: Presumably the feature of printing out the source lines is simply not implemented in the old version of asan. You're probably better off fixing whatever is preventing you from upgrading to a recent compiler

Comment: Me, I'm impressed that anything as old as the 4.8 line HAS sanitizer support.